# The work area "LT_MARC" is not long enough. long enough

Tags: abap

I am getting below error, how to fix it?

> The work area "LT_MARC" is not long enough. long enough.

Code:

```
DATA: lt_marc TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF marc.

SELECT * FROM marc AS mc 
    INNER JOIN mara AS mm 
        ON mm~matnr = mc~matnr
    into table lt_marc 
    WHERE mm~laeda >= 20230801.
```

Update: Using RSDU_EXEC_SQL I was able to execute above SQL Query. Not sure why class cl_sql_statement method execute_query not executing above query.

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12663636/error--the-work-area-is-not-long-enough-long-enoug.html) anwser your question?

Comment: I would answer with a question: which columns do you think `SELECT *` do output with 2 joined tables?

Comment: @DarkBee, I am now getting this error : "Invalid numeric value for parameter/column (243) source type NVARCHAR, target type DECIMAL" for this query. 
"SELECT MC.* FROM MARC AS MC INNER JOIN MARA AS MM ON MM.MATNR = MC.MATNR WHERE MM.LAEDA >= 20230801". 

I am using this class: cl_sql_statement to trigger SQL.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the changes you've made and the new error you've gotten

Comment: Hello @DarkBee, Now its working I used the program RSDU_EXEC_SQL to execute.  Its coming correct. I am not sure why this class did not executed the above mentioned SQL. Thank you so much DarkBee for the Help.

Comment: @PriyankaMishra An error like "Invalid numeric value for column" usually occurs in a `SELECT` when you are using `SELECT ... INTO` with a table that does not exactly match the output of the `SELECT`. In that case the ABAP interpreter will try to put the first column of the SELECT into the first column of the table, the second into the second, and so on regardless of what actually belongs there. Which is usually not what you want. What you usually want in that case is `SELECT ... INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the `SELECT *` in combination of `INNER JOIN` you are selecting the fields of both `marc` **and** `mara`. But your internal table is a `TABLE OF marc`, which means that it is missing the fields of `mara`.

### Solution A

Instead of `SELECT *` use a list of the fields of those tables you are actually going to need (this will also improve the performance of the query, by the way). Then declare `lt_marc` as a table of a custom type that has only the fields you want. For example:

```
TYPES: 
  BEGIN OF ty_data_struct,
      matnr TYPE matnr,
      ersda TYPE ersda,
      werks TYPE werks_d,
      mmsta TYPE mmsta,
  END OF ty_data_struct.
DATA: lt_marc TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_data_struct.

SELECT mara~matnr
       mara~ersda
       marc~werks
       marc~mmsta
 FROM marc AS mc 
 INNER JOIN mara AS mm 
    ON mm~matnr = mc~matnr
 into table lt_marc 
 WHERE mm~laeda >= '20230801'.
```

Keep in mind that with this solution, the fields of `ty_data_struct` and the list of fields after `SELECT` must be in the same order and have the same type (but not necessarily in name). Otherwise the `SELECT` will try to write the data into the wrong columns of your internal table, which will give you an error if you are lucky and give you junk data if you are unlucky. So with this solution you have to be careful that when you change your mind about what fields you want to select, you have to do that change at two places synchronously.

### Solution B

Instead of `INTO TABLE`,  use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE`. That way the `SELECT` will only fill the fields you have in the target table (by name). So if you really want *all* the fields of `marc` and *none* of the fields of `mara` (but still want a `JOIN` for some reason) you can do this:

```
 DATA: lt_marc TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF marc.

SELECT * FROM marc AS mc 
    INNER JOIN mara AS mm 
        ON mm~matnr = mc~matnr
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_marc 
    WHERE mm~laeda >= 20230801.
```

### Solution C

Instead of defining the table type explicitly with `DATA variable TYPE type`, use an inline declaration with the `DATA(variable)` syntax. That way the ABAP interpreter will automatically generate a custom type with all the fields you are selecting:

```
SELECT * FROM marc AS mc 
    INNER JOIN mara AS mm 
        ON mm~matnr = mc~matnr
    INTO TABLE  @DATA(lt_marc )
    WHERE mm~laeda >= '20230801'.
```

This is the solution I would usually favor. I would still recommend to use a field list instead of `SELECT *` with this approach. Because I seriously doubt that you are going to need *all* the fields of *both* tables. When you combine `INTO @DATA(var)` with a field list, then you will generate much less database load (especially on SAP HANA). Also, the resulting internal table you select into will only have the fields you selected, saving you memory on the application server.